# Multi-threaded socket client for Scrolls

Tags: python, multithreading, socket

This is a multi-threaded socket client written to talk to the [Scrolls](http://scrolls.com) socket server. The idea is to send commands to the socket server and respond to messages received via callbacks. I've never done multi-threading before and would like the code reviewed for code correctness, best practices, and potential issues regarding how I'm handling threading.

[GitHub](https://github.com/david-torres/ScrollsSocketClient)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64encode
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
import socket
import json
import time


class PingThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, scrolls_client):
        self.scrolls_client = scrolls_client
        self.stopped = False
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            self.scrolls_client.send({'msg': 'Ping'})
            time.sleep(10)


class MessageThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, scrolls_client):
        self.scrolls_client = scrolls_client
        self.stopped = False
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            # grab a message from queue
            message = self.scrolls_client.queue.get()

            # make a copy of the current subscribers to keep this thread-safe
            current_subscribers = dict(self.scrolls_client.subscribers)

            # send message to subscribers
            for subscriber_key, subscriber_callback in current_subscribers.iteritems():
                # msg or op should match what we asked for
                if 'msg' in message and message['msg'] == subscriber_key:
                    subscriber_callback(message)
                elif 'op' in message and message['op'] == subscriber_key:
                    subscriber_callback(message)

            # signals to queue job is done
            self.scrolls_client.queue.task_done()


class ReceiveThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, scrolls_client):
        self.scrolls_client = scrolls_client
        self.stopped = False
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            self.scrolls_client.receive()


class ScrollsSocketClient(object):
    """
    A Python client for the Scrolls socket server.

    Usage:
    YOUR_SCROLLS_EMAIL = 'user@example.com'
    YOUR_SCROLLS_PASSWORD = 'password'

    scrolls = ScrollsApi(YOUR_SCROLLS_EMAIL, YOUR_SCROLLS_PASSWORD)

    """

    queue = Queue()
    subscribers = {}
    _socket_recv = 8192
    _scrolls_host = '54.208.22.193'
    _scrolls_port = 8081
    _scrolls_publickey = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCYUK5tWE8Yb564e5VBs05uqh38
mLSRF76iHY4IVHtpXT3FiI6SWoVDyOAiAAe/IJwzUmjCp8V4nmNX26nQuHR4iK/c
U9G7XhpBLfmQx0Esx5tJbYM0GR9Ww4XeXj3xZZBL39MciohrFurBENTFtrlu0EtM
3T8DbLpZaJeXTle7VwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.connect((self._scrolls_host, self._scrolls_port))

        self.ping_thread = PingThread(self)
        self.message_thread = MessageThread(self)
        self.receive_thread = ReceiveThread(self)

        # self.ping_thread.start()
        self.receive_thread.start()
        self.message_thread.start()

    def login(self):
        login_params = {
            'msg': 'SignIn',
            'email': self._encrypt(self.email),
            'password': self._encrypt(self.password)
        }
        self.send(login_params)
        self.ping_thread.start()

    def subscribe(self, event, callback):
        # add subscribers
        self.subscribers[event] = callback

    def unsubscribe(self, event):
        # rm subscribers
        self.subscribers.pop(event)

    def send(self, params):
        # send message
        self.socket.send(json.dumps(params))

    def receive(self):
        stream_data = ''
        data_json = None

        while (1):
            # read data from the buffer
            data = self.socket.recv(self._socket_recv)

            if not data:
                # no more data being transmitted
                break
            else:
                # append data to the response
                stream_data += data
                try:
                    # line breaks means we are handling multiple responses
                    if stream_data.find("\n\n"):
                        # split and parse each response
                        for stream_data_line in stream_data.split("\n\n"):
                            # try to load as JSON
                            data_json = json.loads(stream_data_line)

                            # we have a response, add it to the queue
                            self.queue.put(data_json)
                except:
                    # invalid json, incomplete data
                    pass

    def quit(self):
        # stop all threads and close the socket
        self.receive_thread.stopped = True
        self.receive_thread._Thread__stop()

        self.message_thread.stopped = True
        self.message_thread._Thread__stop()

        self.ping_thread.stopped = True
        self.ping_thread._Thread__stop()

        self.socket.close()

    def _encrypt(self, data):
        key = RSA.importKey(self._scrolls_publickey)
        cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
        encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt(data)
        return b64encode(encrypted_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Thread.__init__(self)
```

Do (for example):

```
super(MessageThread, self).__init__()
```

Also it's more Pythonic to do:

```
while True:
```

Instead of:

```
while (1):
```

Instead of using the stopped variables, it may be more efficient to use a variable such as:

```
self.active = True
```

That way you can do this which saves you from having to do extra processing on the "not" every iteration:

```
while self.active:
```

Even better though may be to just do while True and instead of setting stopped to True and calling *Thread*_stop(), just call exit() on the threads, then you shouldn't need the stopped variables at all.

Also in receive() you could simplify it slightly

```
def receive(self):
    stream_data = ''

    while True:
        # read data from the buffer
        data = self.socket.recv(self._socket_recv)

        if not data:
            # no more data being transmitted
            return # now you don't need an else

        # append data to the response
        stream_data += data
        try:
            # line breaks means we are handling multiple responses
            if stream_data.find("\n\n"):
                # split and parse each response
                for stream_data_line in stream_data.split("\n\n"):

                    # we have a response, add it to the queue
                    # no need to store json.loads result that's only used once
                    self.queue.put(json.loads(stream_data_line))
        except:
            # invalid json, incomplete data
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it's the invaluable Python style guide. One such suggestion is to structure your modules so that all the plain `import` statements are first, separated from the `from _ import _` lines. It's neater and easier to read.

```
import socket
import json
import time

from base64 import b64encode
from threading import Thread

from Queue import Queue
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
```

Why are you using two different `if` statements to run the same line? If you need to run it in either case, use `or`, not an `elif`.

```
            if ('msg' in message and message['msg'] == subscriber_key or
                'op' in message and message['op'] == subscriber_key):
                subscriber_callback(message)
```

If you're going to have a comment under a function declaration, you should make it a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) so that it can be useful to others reading your code (as docstrings are accessible programmatically through the interpreter).

```
def subscribe(self, event, callback):
    """Add subscribers"""
```

Though in that particular case it seems pretty clear what `subscribe` does to me.

Your `receive` function has a lot of unnecessary comments, I'd strip them out especially in places that are pretty clear from the actual code. In particular:

```
        if not data:
            # no more data being transmitted
            break
        else:
            # append data to the response
            stream_data += data
```

Instead of using `str.find(s)` use `if s in str`. It's faster and more Pythonic:

```
                if "\n\n" in stream_data:
```

Never use `except` without giving it a specific exception to look for. If you made a syntax error like a typo then you'd actually not notice because of that `except` and you'd probably think there was a problem with the JSON. If you're looking for errors from invalid JSON, that raises a `ValueError`, so raise that instead.

```
            except ValueError:
                # invalid json, incomplete data
                pass
```